# how to authenticate log entries from mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, logentries

I am new to the log entries. I am working on query log entries from my mvc application. Before doing that i want to authenticate the my log entries account .how can i do that.I have read the documentation file in log entries https://docs.logentries.com/docs/authentication but i didn't find the rest api for authentication .Is i need to install any packages to authenticate. I go the rest api for get query but not for authentication .Is authentication is different process? Please help me out from this problem.

Advance thanks!

Comment: Install log4net from nuget and use it.

Comment: @Aby i think log4net is used for create new logs or else we can call rest api ?

Comment: @Aby Can you provide a sample code for authenticate the log entries from c#.